# supertest fails to parse status code 400

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I have been running into some issues with supertest, mocha, and node with parsing status code 400.

Here is my `index.js` code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/api/tweets', function(req, res) {
    var userId = req.query.userId;

    if (!userId) {
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }

});

module.exports = app;
```

when I do `mocha test.js` this is the printout I get:

```
Test:
1) respond with status code 400 for GET /api/tweets with missing userId


0 passing (75ms)
1 failing

1) Test: respond with status code 400 for GET /api/tweets with missing userId:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
  at net.js:1419:10
```

Here is the code for `test.js`:

```
var request = require('supertest')

describe('Test:', function() {
  var server = require('./index')
  it('respond with status code 400 for GET /api/tweets with missing userId', function(done) {
request(server)
  .get('/api/tweets?userId')
  .expect(400, done)
  })
})
```

Are there any pointers that could be given? I'm not sure why node/supertest are giving me such an odd error.

My setup is as follows:

NVM is installed, but it is using the system node version (0.12.3).

Thanks in advance for your help!

-Stu.

Answer (score 1):

> Supertest ... Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

I got this above error when testing over a secure connection. I fixed it by adding `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` as an env var on the test run.

For those wondering why this happens, it can happen because '127.0.0.1' is not listed as a valid IP in your certificate. The underlying error is:

> Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "IP: 127.0.0.1 is not in the cert's list:

However, you will not see this error message, just the spurious and much disliked "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of supertest and express? There were some big changes with supertest 1.0.0 by way of a new version of superagent that changed how ["error" responses](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/613) were handled for non 2xx responses.

This test worked for me using express 4.12.2 and supertest 1.0.1

```
var request = require('supertest')
, express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/api/tweets', function(req, res) {
  var userId = req.query.userId;
  if (!userId) {
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
});

describe.only('GET /api/tweets', function() {
  it('should respond with HTTP 400 for missing userId', function(done) {
    request(app)
    .get('/api/tweets?userId')
    .expect(400, done);
  });
  it('should respond with HTTP 200 with userId', function(done) {
    request(app)
    .get('/api/tweets?userId=100')
    .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```